# Problem proving continuous map theorem for convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

I'm trying to proof the continuous mapping theorem in the context of convergence in probability. I'm following the book "Modern Probability Theory" by B. Ramdas (pages 145-146). Please refer to this [link](https://books.google.es/books?id=ysv3Jycux04C&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=mutual%20convergence%20in%20probability&source=bl&ots=xblO5OLgKB&sig=rNoA6b-WateWeVsupj7_aC3MIPE&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAGoVChMI8YHrkOnQyAIVgVIUCh0PLQXk#v=onepage&q&f=false).

At some point he's got the following:

> $P[|X_n-X| < \zeta,|X| \leq a] \leq P[|f(X_n)-f(X)| < \eta,|X|\leq a]$

Then it says the following:

> But $P[|X_n-X|<\zeta,|X|\leq a]+P[|X_n-X|<\zeta,|X| > a]=\\
> > =P[|X_n-X| < \zeta] \geq 1-\epsilon$

I really don't know what am I missing when he concludes that

$1-2\epsilon < P[|X_n-X| < \zeta,|X| \leq a]$

Basically I don't see how he estimates the term $P[|X_n-X|<\zeta,|X| > a]$

Comment: It looks like Ramdas intended to choose $a$ so large that $P(|X|>a)<\epsilon$. (This guess is based on the discussion prior to the Theorem. In the proof as written, $a$ is unspecified.)